# How do I setup KnowledgeTree with a publicly accessible folder?

Tags: document-management

I've been asked to setup KnowledgeTree (http://www.knowledgetree.com/) for a client of mine. KnowledgeTree seems to do user-authenticated DMS very well, but they want the option of having a folder that has world public-read access so they can share links to this folder with the rest of the world.

The only problem is that for the life of me I simply cannot figure out how to make KT do this. I have read in the docs about anonymous access and setting access for an "everyone" role but KT won't let me create a role of everyone.

I'm using the Community Edition of KT v3.6.3

Thanks,
Seth

Answer (score 0):

I came across your post while looking for an answer to the very question you're asking.  I figured out the answer last night and feel the right thing is to share it with you and others who may be struggling with this as we did.

1. Log in as an Administrator
2. Navigate to the "DMS Administration" area
3. Go to System Configuration
4. Go to General Settings
5. Scroll to Session Management
6. Allow Anonymous log in
7. Create the public directory
8. Edit the directory's permissions to include the role named "Everyone"

If you follow these steps, all documents in the public directory will be accessible without requiring a username and password.

Hope this helps

Best, 
Carlos

Comment: I have followed your instructions, but when I logout from admin and re-visit the site as anonymous, the public folder is not appearing in the "browse documents" link?

Answer (score 0):

If public access doesn't need to be via KT, consider enabling the WebDAV feature in KT.

If you have a Linux-based web server, you can then use davfs2 to mount the specific KT folders as local folders on the web server.  I use davfs2 to provide document access via my wiki.  This can probably be done on Windows using similar tools/techniques.